# Can I use the environment to add/replace to the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

Within a CMakeLists.txt file, you can write something like:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")
```

but what if I want to "prime" that variable before the invocation of CMake? Using the environment, perhaps? Is this possible?

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH) says it is empty by default, but I was hoping to diverge from this default.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred option would be to pass this to cmake at the time of configuration.

**Using command line options**

```
cmake -D "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH:STRING=${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}" -S ...
```

or

**Using a cache configuration script**

```
# initialCache.cmake

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} CACHE STRING "path to look for cmake modules")
```

```
cmake -C initialCache.cmake -S ...
```

or

**Using a preset**

CMakePresets.json

```json
{
  "version": 3,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 19,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "mypreset",
      "displayName": "My preset",
      "description": "Preset using the environment variable to set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH": {
          "type": "STRING",
          "value": "$env{CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
cmake --preset mypreset -S ...
```

Answer (score 0):

CMAKE_MODULE_PATH is not an ["cmake-env-variable"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html). It won't read same name environment variable to initialize it automatically. As an example, `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` can be initialized from env var ([ref](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/envvar/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html#envvar:CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)).

An alternative for your situation:

```
if(DEFINED ENV{CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "$ENV{CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
else()
  message(WARNING "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH env var not defined, using the default empty one")
endif()
```

Comment: The whole point is that I don't want to have to make `CMakeList.txt` changes in my particular scenario. So, I take it your answer is "no you can't"?

Comment: I just use another variable, `ARTIFACTS_DIR`, for my own cross-project, cross-machine, cross-platform dependency(library files, header files) searching. It might be good to have a package manager.